# How do I list current running Stored Procedures with SMO?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, smo

I am using C#, SQL Server 2008 and SQL Management Objects, and I need to know if there is a way to get the current executing Stored Procedure(s) using SMO/C#. I have some long-running Stored Procedures and I need to monitor their current status by determining whether they are idle or executing. Can this be done with SMO? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to back into it with the [EnumProccesses](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms210360.aspx) method on the Server object. I really feel like this is a case of "when you have a hammer, everything looks like a nail", though. That is, you'll be able to do a lot better with raw T-SQL against system views like sys.dm_exec_requests

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Ben Thul, the following SQL statement from [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/taylaf/archive/2010/01/25/determine-the-currently-executing-statement-in-a-long-running-sql-stored-procedure.aspx) should do the job (though I haven't tested it):

```
SELECT  requests.session_id, 
    requests.status, 
    requests.command, 
    requests.statement_start_offset,
    requests.statement_end_offset,
    requests.total_elapsed_time,
    details.text
FROM    sys.dm_exec_requests requests
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text (requests.plan_handle) details
WHERE   requests.session_id > 50
ORDER BY total_elapsed_time DESC
```